# UITabbarController setting initial view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

In my app, I have 5 tabs for navigation.

However I would like my middle tab (tab 3) to be the one that is first displayed when the app is first loaded.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: tabBarController.selectedIndex=2; simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first loaded means first time ever? or for every new launch? this code is for first time ever, but without `NSUserDefault` can be used to every new launch

appDelegate.h

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

appDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

 UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem5 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

 if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"first"]) {

    //first launch selected third tabBarItem
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"first"];

  }
```